# C++ conversion operator for base type in templated wrapper

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a wrapper template class that allows conversion as if the templated type was used. I'm not sure how to write the template code to make this functional. See the code below:

```
class Base { }
class Derived : public Base { }

template <typename ObjectT>
class Wrapper {

    ...
    
    // Implicit conversion to base types
    template <class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T, ObjectT>::value>>
    operator Wrapper<T>() const {
        return Wrapper<T>(data);
    };
    
    // Explicit conversion required for other types that are convertable
    template <class T, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<ObjectT, T>::value>>
    explicit operator Wrapper<T>() const {
        return Wrapper<T>(data);
    };
}
```

I would like to use Wrapper like this:

```
Wrapper<Base> wrapper = Wrapper<Derived>(); // Implicit conversion to base
Wrapper<float> wrapper = (Wrapper<float>)Wrapper<int>(); // float int requires explicit conversion, but is allowed
```

As of right now, this code gives me a compiler error since std::is_convertible<ObjectT, T> is also true for Base, Derived and thus creates the template function twice creating an ambiguous function

`member function already defined or declared`

Comment: Could you just make the second operator be enabled if `is_convertable && !is_base_of`?

Comment: @vandench Totally, I just don't know how to write that with templates

Comment: IIRC the first template parameter of `enable_if` is just a boolean, and the value member of `is_convertible` and `is_base_of` are both booleans, so it should be as simple as the literal example I gave, albeit with the template parameters and accessing the value member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <typename ObjectT>
struct Wrapper {
  // Implicit conversion to base types
  template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, ObjectT>>* = nullptr>
  operator Wrapper<T>() const;
  
  // Explicit conversion required for other types that are convertable
  template <class T, std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_base_of_v<T, ObjectT> && std::is_convertible_v<ObjectT, T>>* = nullptr>
  explicit operator Wrapper<T>() const;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/ahhvfe7Tn)

Comment: That worked, thanks